# jQuery append alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am really struggling with this for a while so i guessed maybe SO knows the solution.

I created a live search which (after you searched for a product id) shows up a row with... a product like so (simplified):

```
<div id="78524" class="live_search_product">
   <!-- productinformation here -->
</div>
```

Underneath this there is a product list which has products in it. These products are alphanumerically sorted like this:

```
<div class="products_wrapper">
  <div id="78500">
     <!-- productinformation here -->
  </div>
  <div id="78501">
     <!-- productinformation here -->
  </div>

  (id 78524 should come here when clicked)

  <div id="78526">
    <!-- productinformation here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

What i want:

When you click on the `.live_search_product` product it needs to put itself 'between' the correct id's ascending, i can't figure this out and i don't see the logic behind this.

Can you guys give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you elaborate a bit what's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a list of IDs, sort it and then determine at which index the new element should be placed and insert it after element on `index - 1`:

```js
const $list = $('#product-list');
$('.live_search_product').on('click', function() {

  const $this = $(this);
  const thisId = +$this.attr('id');
  const ids = [];
  $list.find('div').each(function() {
    ids.push(+$(this).attr('id'));
  });
  ids.push(thisId);
  
  ids.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
  
  const index = ids.findIndex(function(el) { return el === thisId; });
  $this.insertAfter($list.find('div').eq(index - 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="78524" class="live_search_product">
   Product 78524 info product info product info [click me]
</div>

List:
<div id="product-list">
  <div id="78500">
     Product 78500 info product info product info
  </div>
  <div id="78501">
     Product 78501 info product info product info
  </div>

  (id 78524 should come here when clicked)

  <div id="78526">
     Product 78526 info product info product info
  </div>
</div>
```